# Conditional structure with 4 conditionals in JAGS

Tags: bayesian, jags

I'm using JAGS for Bayesian estimation.
Ideally, I would like to define 4 different scenarios (x=a, x=b, x=c, x=d). Depending on the scenario, some different actions should be done.
My problem is that JAGS seems to lack if-else statements that serve to control flow.
How should I write a conditional statement with four options?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.